# Attempting to parse a WAV file, memcpy results are unexpected

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

Assume that I have a small WAV file I've opened and dumped as a array of `char` for processing.

Right now, I am attempting to `memcpy` the `fmt` chunk ID into a 4 byte buffer.

```
char fmt[4];
memcpy(fmt_chunk_id, raw_file + 12, sizeof(char) * 4);
```

From my understanding of `memcpy`, this will copy the 4 bytes starting at offset 12 into `fmt`. However, when I go to debug the program I get some very strange output:

[image]

It seems to copy the `fmt` section correctly, but now for some reason I have a bunch of garbage after it. Interestingly, this garbage comes *before* format at offset bytes 0 (`RIFF`), and 8 (`WAVE`). It is a little endian file (`RIFF`).

I can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting data from the *beginning* of the buffer at the *end* of this given that I only copied 4 bytes worth of data (which should exactly fit the first 4 characters `f` `m` `t` and space).

What is going on here? The output seems to indicate to me I'm somehow over-reading memory somewhere - but if that was the case I'd expect garbage rather than the previous offset's data.

EDIT:

If it matters, the data type of `raw_file` is `const char* const`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger is showing you an area of memory which has been dynamically allocated on the stack.

What is in all probability happening is that you read data from the file, and even if you asked to read, say, 50 bytes, the underlying system might have decided to read more (1024, 2048, or 4096 bytes usually). So those bytes passed around in memory, likely some on the stack, *and that stack is being reused by your function now*. If you asked to read more than those four bytes, then this is even more likely to happen.

Then the debugger sees that you are pointing to a string, but in C strings run until they get terminated by a zero (ASCIIZ). So what you're shown is the first four bytes *and everything else that followed, up to the first 0x00 byte*.

If that's important to you, just

```
char fmt[5];
fmt[4] = 0;
// read four bytes into fmt.
```

Now the debugger will only show you the first four bytes.

*But now you see why you should always scrub and overwrite sensitive information from a memory area before free()ing it -- the data might remain there and even be reused or dumped by accident.*

Comment: Ah this is interesting. So I've read the data correctly, but the _debugger_ reading the memory is reading up to the next null terminating byte? Wow, I'm glad I ran into this. That is good to know. Is it best practice to set the null terminator like you've done?

Comment: Not at all, unless you want to manipulate `fmt` as a string. In that case yes, it's *strongly* advised to make it into a string as soon as possible.